# Convergence in distribution implies $f_n^{(1)}, f_n^{(2)}, f_n^{(3)}$ all converge to $f^{(1)}, f^{(2)}, f^{(3)}$?

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

Suppose $X_n, X$ are random variables with CDF $F_n, F$.

I know that convergence in distribution defines convergence in CDF sense. If we know that $X_n \to X$ in distribution, can we say that
$f_n^{(k)} \to f^{(k)}$ as well?  ($f$ denotes a density function, which is continuous and differentiable. $f^{(k)}$ denotes its $k$th derivative.)

Comment: Are we assuming, e.g., that $f_n^{(1)}\to g$ and you want to show $g = f^{(1)}$?

Comment: No, I mean, convergence in distribution (in CDF sense) implies convergence in all derivatives (including density, first derivative of density, and so on). You can assume any continuity and differentiability if needed

Answer (score 1):

No.  In particular,

- it is possible for all the $F_n$ to have an arbitrary large number of derivatives (including a density) but $F$ not to have a derivative (think continuous random variable approximations to the CDF of a discrete random variable)
- it is possible for none of the $F_n$ to have a derivative but $F$ to have an arbitrary large number of derivatives (think of the Central Limit Theorem applied to a discrete random variable)

If you want everything differentiable, consider $x \in [0,1]$ and the distributions with $F_n(x) = x -\frac{1}{n\pi}\sin(n\pi x)$.  Then $F_n$ converges to $F(x)=x$ on this interval, but each density $f_n(x)$ varies between $0$ and $2$, not converging to $f(x)=1$

Comment: Thanks Henry. But what if we suppose everything is differentiable? I want to see the condition(s) on which the statement holds. I cannot come up with a counter example

Comment: @Jayboy That would still not work - I have added an example

Comment: nice counterexample...thanks a lot Henry!